# Best way to select parts of a complex model?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I want to make [this treasure chest](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2294031/files) wider ("scale" on X-axis).
Is there a good way to select the left and the right part of the model to drag it a little apart? I know of the "b" shortcut to select a rectangle region, but is is very tedious. What is the effective way to select the right vertices to drag/scale the crate wider?

[image]

Comment: the circle select (C) or the lazo select? also, topology is not that good and some tool won't work well...

Comment: Answer above is right mate. The problm of the model is that its from "tris" (triangles) so the topo is horrible and probably also the render will be (cause the SubSurf is NOT an option here). Because of this also the selection of "right" part of the mesh for Yo scaling/moveing will be MUCH harder to choose. Try to use "B" key from the desired side using the orthographic view and ENABLE "limit selection to visible" to choose only the visible vertices and then unselect the rest U dont want to use.